# Replace directory name in url with another name

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Using htaccess, how can I change the url "http://www.website.com/abc/..." to "http://www.website.com/xyz/..." so it acts as a redirect to the same filename/directory structure after "xyz" as it did after "abc".

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^abc/(.*)$ /xyz/$1 [R=302,L,QSA]
```

This will redirect `example.com/abc/pink-kitten` to `example.com/xyz/pink-kitten` (or `example.com/abc/` to `example.com/xyz/`) but will not do anything if trailing slash after the folder name is missing (i.e. `example.com/abc` will not be redirected). If you need the last case as well then you will need to use separate rule for that.

You can change redirect code `[R=302]` to another if required (e.g. 301 Permanent Redirect).